# Can anyone tell me what game these dice come from?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

There are 7 d6 and a d10.  Sides contain horseshoes, crossbows, swords, wings, faces, etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are absolutely Dragon dice. I love that game. I recently found out that they still exist. Someone bought the rights from TSR and has been making new dice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could it be you have [Dragon Dice?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Dice) Looks like this particular photo includes D8 not D10.

[image: Dragon Dice Image]

Comment: I think that is it.  Looks just like those and a look around shows others that are just like them as well.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Definitely dragon dice. I bought that game but never found anyone to play with.

Comment: you too? I thought I was the only one with hundreds of cool dice that no one else knew anything about. I eventually just got rid of them. Of course I regret that now.

Comment: @OmarKooheji Same here.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if these are the ten-siders in question (faces, battleaxes, wings)...

[image]

This is a Dragon Dice expansion of some kind, though I couldn't tell you which monsters these particular dice represent...